# ListWheelScrollView con imágenes comienza desplazado a la derecha

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy utilizando un ListWheelScrollView para hacer una lista de items que, por supuesto, llevan imágenes, el problema es que al iniciarse la app, se ve con este aspecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tras mover el scroll un poco arriba y abajo, curiosamente se corrige y se ve como debería verse:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las imágenes están metidas en un asset a través de la propia app, es decir, no se están cogiendo de ninguna URL ni se tienen que cargar desde fuera ni nada.

Aquí dejo el código de la tarjeta que lleva la imagen:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SelectActivityButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectActivityButton(
      {super.key,
      required this.text,
      required this.image,
      required this.routeName});

  final String text;
  final String image;
  final String routeName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        elevation: 10,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              //Image.asset(image, height, widht)
              Image.asset(
                image,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(text),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Y aquí el código donde se genera la lista:

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeViewState createState() => HomeViewState();
}

class HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final _scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();

  static const double _itemHeight = 450;
  static const int _itemCount = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<HomeViewModel>(
      builder: (context, model, child) => model.state == ViewState.busy
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Scaffold(
              key: _scaffoldKey,
              body: ClickableListWheelScrollView(
                scrollController: _scrollController,
                itemHeight: _itemHeight,
                itemCount: _itemCount,
                onItemTapCallback: (index) {
                  if (kDebugMode) {
                    print("Entrando a la actividad");
                  }
                  model.routingActivities(index, context);
                },
                child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemExtent: _itemHeight,
                  //physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                  diameterRatio: 2.5,
                  //offAxisFraction: -0.5,
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
                    print(index);
                  },
                  childDelegate: ListWheelChildListDelegate(children: [
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadCompras,
                      image: "assets/tarjeta_actividades/Cat-Compras.jpg",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadAlimentacion,
                      image: "assets/tarjeta_actividades/Cat-Compras.jpg",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadAgua,
                      image: "assets/tarjeta_actividades/Cat-Compras.jpg",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadResiduos,
                      image: "assets/tarjeta_actividades/Cat-Compras.jpg",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadTransporte,
                      image: "assets/tarjeta_actividades/Cat-Compras.jpg",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(viewPoints);
                },
                label: const Text('Puntos'),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.point_of_sale),
                backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Decir que estoy usando un paquete adicional para que se le pueda hacer click a los elementos del ListWheelScrollView, pero, antes de usar ese paquete, sucedía también el mismo problema. Por otro lado, hasta ahora solo he testeado la app en un emulador de Android ¿sucedería lo mismo en un teléfono real?